# SQLAlchemy.exc.OperationalError : (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, runtime-error

run.py file:

```
from flaskblog import app, db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

models.py file:

```
from flaskblog import db
from datetime import datetime



class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    img_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpeg')

    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{ self.username }', '{ self.email }', '{ self.img_file }')"



class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User { self.title }, { self.date_posted })"
```

**init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hard to guess'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)


from flaskblog import routes
```

I have tried creating the table using the terminal before running the app using `db.create_all()` but it still didn't work.
The following error is thrown:

```
SQLAlchemy.exc.OperationalError : (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user
```

If anyone could solve this problem, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: After you create the table, can you manually open the `site.db` file using the `sqlite3` command line client and verify that it really is there?

Comment: try putting `db.create_all()` after your model schema. You have to use the same instance of  `SQLAlchemy`, so in your model definition, you have to import these instance

Comment: If you're using `flask run` to start the app, that `if` block at the bottom where the `db.create()` is won't execute.

Answer (score 2):

```
#from flaskblog import db <- this import is wrong!

from my_project_name import db # the instancfe of SQLAlchemy that you use in your app
from datetime import datetime



class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    img_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpeg')

    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{ self.username }', '{ self.email }', '{ self.img_file }')"



class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User { self.title }, { self.date_posted })"
```